# Webpack issue with 3rd party library

Tags: ios, angular, webpack, applepay

I am trying to use apply pay js SDK in my angular project. After importing the apple pay JS script, My webpage stops loading with the following exception:

[image: Console error stacktrace]

I am new to angular touching an old project to add apple pay as an option. I have found various articles on net explaining webpack 5 will resolve this issue but I am not able to understand how to integrate webpack5. Without apply pay JS SDK, it works fine. Following is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "ACB",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "2.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.1.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/google.analytics": "0.0.40",
    "angular-cc-library": "^1.2.5",
    "angular2-recaptcha": "^1.1.0",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.1",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "^1.0.10",
    "ngx-embed-video": "^0.3.0",
    "ngx-quill-editor": "^2.2.2",
    "@ng-web-apis/common": "^1.12.0",
    "@ng-web-apis/payment-request": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-spinner": "6.0.0",
    "rxjs": "6.3.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "6.3.3",
    "safe-pipe": "^0.3.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^7.32.2",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.7.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "shallow-render": "^6.2.1",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

My app.html code -

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ACB</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<script src="https://applepay.cdn-apple.com/jsapi/v1/apple-pay-sdk.js"></script>
<script>
  (function(i, s, o, g, r, a, m) {
            i['GoogleAnalyticsObject'] = r;
            i[r] = i[r] || function() {
                (i[r].q = i[r].q || []).push(arguments)
            }, i[r].l = 1 * new Date();
            a = s.createElement(o),
                m = s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];
            a.async = 1;
            a.src = g;
            m.parentNode.insertBefore(a, m)
        })(window, document, 'script', 'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js', 'ga');
</script>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: If possible, we will want a solution without any major version upgrades (like angular 12 or later)

Comment: So all you did was adding that apple pay sdk script to your index..? It would be strange if that would cause a webpack issue..?

Comment: Also, if you look at those error, every bundle is giving this error so it seems unrelated to that script tag. My guess is your node version is incorrect for your (old!) angular version.

Comment: it may have triggered something but yes the only change i did was adding the apple pay sdk script to index.

My node version is v10.24.1 @MikeOne

Comment: Actually.. it looks like you cli version is too low for the Angular version used (and your node version is too high). You might want to try downgrading Node to 8.9x and then run npm i @angular/cli@^6

Comment: Trying that now, but sadly running into other compatibility issues. Legacy projects are hard to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked fine on Node 8.9.4 and angular-cli^6